# How to retrigger a js event cancelled with preventdefault()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Having the following **React** code:

```
// foo element
<NavLink onClick={(e) => this.sectionSelected(e)} />

//method invoqued
sectionSelected(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // foo actions   
    // this.setState( ... )

    // trigger the click again
    // e.retrigger() 
}
```

How can I retrigger the click that I cancelled using `preventDefault` ?

Looking for an answer not involving jquery.

Comment: You can simply remove `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @ArslanTariq it seems you don't understand the question, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to suspend default event behaviour in the way you want.

You could wrap the `NavLink` to handle the click AND follow the default behaviour...

```
const NavLinkWithOnClick = ({
 clickHandler,
 to
}) => (
  <div onClick={clickHandler}>
   <NavLink to={to} />
  </div>
)

...

<NavLinkWithOnClick clickHandler={sectionSelected] to="/wherever" />
```